# Get image tag for downloaded file to display

Tags: javascript, file

Instead of li i need to show a file extension image when downloaded file..How can i bind that image to the download url of all the files according to extension.

```
$("<li>").html("<a id='"+ result[i].id +"' href='" + downloadFile(result[i].id) + "'>" + result[i].title + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
```

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't very clear at all.

Comment: I am using google drive sdk and downloading files to my page..When downloading files i am displaying it as a url with bulleted symbol.I need to display fileextension image with the downloaded files(for ex for pdf,pdf extension symbol,for word word extension symbol)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way i can think of is that you check the href ending with javascript.

For example when href="here/some/url/filename.pdf" ends with .pdf you add < img src="pdficon.png" > before the result[i].title.